# NuGet for solution included in TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, nuget

I am having problems with NuGet: it's actually driving me crazy!
I am trying to make a TFS build run for a solution that includes nuget.exe.
I don't have any issues running it from Visual Studio on my local workstation, but when I queue a new build in the TFS server, the build fails with these very known errors:

> D:\<...SolutionPath...>.nuget\nuget.targets (88): Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can also give consent by setting the environment variable 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.
>
> D:\<...SolutionPath...>.nuget\nuget.targets (88): The command ""D:\<...SolutionPath...>.nuget\nuget.exe" install "D:\<...SolutionPath...>\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\<...SolutionPath...>\ "" exited with code 1.

The problem is: I already set the **EnableNuGetPackageRestore** to *true* in the TFS Build server, but it's still throwing the same error. I also tried running nuget.exe with the same parameters FROM a cmd windows in the same TFS server and I don't have any issues.

BTW, this is the content of my NuGet.config:

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="true" />
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that your TFS build service account is the same as the account you used to make the change.  Also reboot the server to make sure the environment variable makes it the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
You mean the EnableNuGetPackageRestore system variable?
Shouldn't that be common to the entire system, meaning all user accounts?

Comment: Have you rebooted the server since making the change?  The service control manager has a long history of not refreshing the environment for services.

Comment: Just to clarify; It's not necessary to reboot the server: you just have to reset the Build Controller Service.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Log on to the build server using the same account that executes the build.**
2. Open Visual Studio.
3. Install the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio.
4. Restart Visual Studio.
5. Tools --> Options --> Package Manager --> General: tick 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build'.
6. Enable package restore in your solution.